# Is correct use she appears not to worry o she doesn't appear to worry

Tags: grammar

She appears not to worry or she doesn't appear to worry Which one  is correct??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean different things.

> She doesn't appear to worry.

This means that there is no evidence of her being concerned. Perhaps she goes about her normal business, in her normal manner.

> She appears not to worry.

This means that there is evidence that she is not concerned. Perhaps she participates in more upbeat activities than normal, or smiles more.

See also [this question and its answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292834/how-to-use-the-infinitive-in-this-sentence/292843).