# In what conditions should the negative of a " that-clause" move to the main clause?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, negation

1. I ***don't*** think **they can win**.
2. I know **they can't win**.

In the " that-clause",
why does the first example use the affirmative, yet the second one use the negative?
I guess the verb "can" or "can't" is bound by ***the subject and the main verb in the main clause***, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The first example uses the affirmative to state what you _don't_ think! If that's what you mean by ''bound by the subject and the main verb', you guess correctly.

Comment: @KateBunting Well, that’s what it says literally, but it’s nearly always used to mean “I think they can’t win”.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Well, I know that, of course! The OP asked why the verb was in the affirmative.

Comment: It's interesting that you've wisely changed the cognitive-domain verb in your example pair. 'I think [that] they can't win' sounds at best unusual. But it still introduces a complication: we're not comparing like with like. While (2) is hyperbole (think Foinavon, Leicester City), it probably means estimating that one is 95+% certain of the outcome. (1) is far less confidently stated. // Using informal _reckon_ as the cognitive-domain verb, which (unusually) works in both variants, I'd say the modal (confidence indication) levels are identical.

Comment: EdwinAshworth has demonstrated the question semantically. I also need answers to explain them grammatically. Just as Kate Bunting said,  the negation of (1) apparently moves from that-clause to main clause grammatically. What grammar rules cause this movement ? In what conditions does the movement happen? (2) is commonly used, given here just for comparison with (1) to indicate the difference. For example,  " I don't know he came" and " I know he didn't come" are both grammatical; they are just literally or semantically different.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth, As I have no idea of the exact name for this movement in linguistics. I checked many grammar books and only found that the movement in a that-clause seemed bound by at least two conditions about the main clause : (a) the main verb should be specific cognitive-domain verbs like " think, believe, suppose, expect, reckon, etc"; (b) the subject should be the first personal pronoun. I need someone's help to verify the rules or provide a reasonable and acceptable explanation of this "movement".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ***thinking*** and ***knowing*** aren't the same thing, so it's almost meaningless to compare positive and negated constructions if the verbs are changed at the same time

Comment: *Syntactically*, there's nothing wrong with saying "I think they can't win". Nor is it "unacceptable" phrasing. It's just *idiomatically* less likely than "I don't think they can win".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Are you sure? If yes, I will throw all my grammar books into the trash can. As I am a non-native speaker of English language, I only need correct grammar.

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure that syntactically there's nothing wrong with *I think they can't win*. But you can just compare *I claim [that] this question is not useful* and *I don't claim [that] this question is useful* to prove to yourself that it usually makes a significant difference to the *meaning* whether you negate the clause *before* "that" or *after* it.

Comment: This phenomenon of negating the matrix (main) clause to imply the negation of the subordinate clause only applies to verbs relating to intention, epistemic stance or opinion (thought or belief), or those which can be used performatively for advice. It is sometimes called *subordinate negation implication*. Your selected answer (which is goodish) deals with only one of these. However, more importantly, it doesn't describe the most important factor in the feasibility of such negations: The verbs concerned must be "medium strength" verbs. This terminology is from CGEL. (continued ...)

Comment: To illustrate: The verbs *suspect, think* and *know* all relate to degrees of belief. *Suspect* indicating a weak degree of belief and *know* indicating a maximum degree of belief. Because these verbs relate to more extreme ends of the belief spectrum, they cannot be used in this way *I don't suspect Bob  lied* is not used to indicate *I suspect Bob didn't lie* and the two won't be considered equivalent in normal circumstances. Similarly with *I don't know that Bob lied* and *I know that Bob didn't lie* However, native speakers who wish to intimate *I think Bob didn't lie*, are very likely ...

Comment: ... to say *I don't think Bob lied* when trying to convey the same information. In fact they are ***far*** more likely to use the latter rather than the former. [The following post might be interesting: "Yeti's"](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17557/position-of-negation-in-an-english-sentence/17570#17570)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntactic rule called [Negative-Raising](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/117681/15299) that operates on a subset of English verbs having to do with perception, thought, and belief. This rule, with these verbs only, allows equivalence between a negative in a complement clause and a negative in the main clause. Since *think* is one of these verbs, the following two sentences are equivalent in meaning:

- *Bill thinks that the Orioles wo**n't** win the Series.*
- *Bill **doesn't** think that the Orioles will win the Series.*

The effect of the rule is that the negation from the *that*-clause seems to rise up to the main clause, where in fact it doesn't apply -- Bill **is** thinking, but that they'll win is not what he's thinking. The literal interpretation some try to push -- that Bill has no opinions -- is not fluent English; nobody talks or writes that way, because that's not what *think* normally means.

However, *claim* is **not** one of these verbs, and thus the following two sentences do **not** mean the same thing:

- *Bill doesn't claim the Orioles will win the Series.*
- *Bill claims the Orioles won't win the Series.*

These **do** have separate senses -- in the first, Bill's belief is unknown, but his claim is denied. In the second, Bill's claim is asserted. But then *claim* is a different verb from *think* -- a claim is public and can be witnessed, but a thought is private and can be denied or imagined. That's what allows Neg-Raising in the first place. Every verb has a different grammar.

Comment: It's quite complicated but understandable and that's what I'm expecting. Can you possibly list out some specific verbs applied to "a subset of English verbs having to do with perception, thought, and belief "?  Let me guess some; are they " think, guess, believe, suppose, expect, reckon, fancy, consider "?

Comment: It's easy enough to search google for neg-raising verbs: https://www.google.com/search?q=neg+raising+verbs

Comment: @ John Lawler, At present, we aren't able to reach GOOGLE due to strict censorship in PRC. They shield it. Thanks all the same.

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes, the ones you suggest -- _think, guess, believe, suppose, expect, reckon, fancy, consider_ -- all allow neg-raising. As do _seem_ and _appear_, but there it's the subject complement that contains the negative; _seem_ and _appear_ are one-place predicates that take clausal subjects, and require either extraposition or subject-raising to move the heavy subject to the end. Any verb that refers to the same things will work the same way; but verbs of speech like _claim_ don't.

Comment: Noted. I just looked up "extraposition" in Collins; it seems very interesting.

Comment: It's a very common rule; [I've discussed it here quite a lot](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20extraposition). There are other phenomena one can search for, as well as [some pre-set searches](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13492/15299) like the one above.